# Bootstrap 3 Embed Image size based on device resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, retina-display

I'm new to Bootstrap 3 and am building my [personal website](http://www.kwarp.com/) with it. I want to include my email on the website, but not in plain text, to protect against spambots. I thought embedding an image would be reasonable, but unfortunately it looks blurry on my iPhone.

Here is the image

[image: email image]

I'm thinking about a few solutions:

1. Embed a 2x version of the image and scale it to half size based
   on device ppi (pixels per inch)
2. Decide to load either a 1x and 2x version of this image based on device ppi
3. Hope spambots don't care and leave my email in plain text

What can I do to gracefully size my image for high-resolution screens?

Answer (score 0):

Use SVG image format that scales nicely on Retina displays

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work because an svg file is implemented in plaintext xml. A spambot could find the email text just as easily as an html file. Here is a snippet from the svg file that I built that has the email in plain text.
`<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 17.9971)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue'" font-size="21">example@example.com</text>`

Answer (score 0):

use this image in background like this.

```
<div class="emailID"></div>

.emailID{
   background-image:url('myemail.png');
   width:100px;
   height:20px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% auto;
}
```